# Looping through an explode() in php weird output

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I'm getting a very weird results  when trying to loop through a comma delimited list in PHP.

It sometimes only outputs a few of them and there seems no logical reason to why it doesn't loop through all of them, and I can't for the life of me figure out what's actually causing it.

My code is:

```
    //pids = &pids=1,2,3,6,7,9
    $pids = $_GET['pids'];
    $photoIdArray = explode(",", $pids);


    for($i = 0; $i <= count($photoIdArray); $i++) {

        foreach($photoIdArray as $j){
            if($i == $j){

                echo "{$j}";

            }
        }

    }

    // result = 1236
```

This is just for testing so there is im not checking the inputs to prevent exploits and what not at the moment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing foreach loop inside of for loop?

Comment: I think I was just overcomplicating it!

Answer (score 3):

Combining 2 loop `for` and `foreach` is overkill for something like this

Try using only `foreach`

```
$pids = "1,2,3,6,7,9";
$photoIdArray = explode(",", $pids);
foreach($photoIdArray as $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

Output

```
 123679
```

Comment: That is the right way to do it, but us I asked him in comment to question, it is important to know why does he want to have foreach inside of for and that if condition...

Comment: @Dušan Radojević  he said the result is ` result = 1236` obviously he wanted `123679`

Comment: @user1726977 overkill , overcomplicating  , overwriting , overlooping , overasking :)

Comment: I didn't wanted to answer such an obvious solution because in that kind of cases I always think maybe that one who ask have some reasons to make something as he did...

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are looping through your values and check if $i is the same as the value. You should check

```
if ($photoIdArray[$i] == $j) {
```

instead of

```
if ($i == $j) {
```

This is the reason it didn't work, but you should still use Baba's method.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dusan, Baba & Co., but to answer the actual question:

Nothing weird happens here. i loops from 0 to 6 (though the array has only indices 0..5), and you compare i with the VALUES of the array, which range from 1 to 9. Of course, only the values 1 to 6 are matched, because i never exceeds 6.

EDIT: Asad and Sietse were faster.